# How do I prevent Ebuild from updating my project dependences

Tags: ebuild

Whenever I run `workspace.xml` it updates the revisions stated in my project's `module.revisions` file. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the EBuild property `update-upstream` to `false`.

To do this, edit `workspace.xml` and find it, making it look like the following:

```
<property name="update-upstream" value="false"/>
```